# unit testing for proprietary ide

Tags: java, unit-testing

I would like to add some sort of unit testing to an IDE known as "IBS Integrator".

how the IDE works:
I write "java-ish" code in .itr files. 
when I press the run button these files are compiled into .class and .java files.
I have no idea what happens next.

Does anyone have advise on how I could make unit testing work in a setup like this?
I was hopping for a framework like phpunit or rspec. I know they are for different langagues but a similar tool for java would be nice. I'm not sure what (if anything) can interact with .class/.java files.

I would prefer something open-source if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since IBS Integrator compiles to .class files, you should be able to write JUnit tests in Java against those classes, and run them however you'd normally run JUnit tests (kick off Ant or Maven, open Eclipse and run them from there, etc.).  And I can't think of any reason to use another technology (phpunit, rspec, etc.) for writing tests of Java code; JUnit seems like the clear winner here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For some reason I was not thinking a test program would work after anything was compiled. I guess I was expecting it to need the actual sources. I will look into JUnit thank you.